# How to connect the nodejs app in docker to external oracle database

Tags: node.js, oracle, docker

I have a node.js app that connects to an external Oracle database, when I run the app on a local machine, it works fine, but when I run it in a docker container, it fails by sending back "errorNum": 12170 to the client.
I have used Oraclelinux image and installed node js and Oracle client and other required tools as shown in my docker file.

I created the container by running the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 3230:5000 -p 1521:1521  --name oratest ora_test:1.0
```

I check the connection to DB by sending a request to localhost:3230/testdb from Postman.

my docker file is:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yum update -y

RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 oracle-nodejs-release-el7 && \
     yum-config-manager --disable ol7_developer_EPEL && \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite nodejs && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum

RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3230 1521
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

my config.env

```
APP_PORT = 5000
ORADBUSER = <MYUSER>
ORADBPSW = <MYPASSWORD>
ORADBCONNECTIONSTRING = <MYDATABASEIP>:1521/<MYSERVICENAME>
```

my sample app

```
const express = require("express");
const dotEnv = require("dotenv");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

const app = express();

dotEnv.config({ path: "./config.env" });

const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 5000;
oracConnect = async () => {
  let connection;
  connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
    user: process.env.ORADBUSER,
    password: process.env.ORADBPSW,
    connectionString: process.env.ORADBCONNECTIONSTRING,
    poolMax: 2,
    poolMin: 2,
    poolIncrement: 0
  });
  return connection;
};

app.use(express.json()); 

app.get("/testdb",async (req,res)=>{
  let connection;    
  try{
    connection = await oracConnect();
    const result = await connection.execute(
    'select current_timestamp from dual'
  );
  res.send(result.rows)
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).send(err);
  console.log(err);
} finally {
  if (connection) {
    try {
      await connection.close();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port} `);  
});
```

Comment: The [comments on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76700515/how-take-access-external-db-in-my-docker-container#comment135224664_76700515) might be of relevance.

Comment: Maybe checkout https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/2410 or other references to ORA-12170.  (A side comment: you should be using a much more recent Instant Client version)

Answer (score 0):

I research a lot to find out what's wrong with my code because it seems everything is ok and should work.
Then I thought maybe something wrong with my network or OS, so after I reinstall my os everything works as expected.